# how to define a Control button l in C# and add special effects and properties to it?

Tags: c#, button, properties

i don't know how to define a control button in c# ? and then define some special properties and effects to it ,rather than what we have in visual studio right now.

Comment: C# is just a language, but what framework are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET WebForms? ASP.NET MVC? Then it might help to get a good basic understanding of that framework before attempting to use it.

Comment: Do you wish to develop a UserControl? If so, as @DavidTischler cited, in where?

Comment: i wish to define a button myself and have it with different kind of special designs and effects, using windows form

Answer (score 1):

Try extending class `System.Windows.Forms.Button`

```
namespace MyDemo {
  public class MyButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button {
      public MyButton() {
         Text = "This is custom text";
         BackColor = Color.Red;
      }
  }
}
```

You should use MyButton class in your application.

Comment: do i have to add any namespaces ?

Comment: is it necessary to use xaml ?

Comment: What do you mean? There's no need for xaml in winforms.

Comment: so I have got wrong information.so all i need to do is adding a class that inherits form button class.right ? and then using it in my app by adding it to my form ? and the i can use events for giving special effects to my button.is there any other special thing to do? or that's all ? (thank you for your help)

Answer (score 0):

To add a property to a button, just use get & set . Here is an example code:

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    string _LockStatus;

    public string LockStatus
    {

        get { return _LockStatus; }

        set { _LockStatus = value; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Off topic - you can use automatic property: `public string LockStatus { get; set; }`

Comment: yes it worked. thank you @Marko.but will you please tell me where i can define inside of that property exactly ? I'm going to use Graphics class to add special effects.